# Hide/Remove "Edit All", "Show Comment" and the directory path from a list form in display mode

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, json

I have the following issue. I have a SharePoint list form (open in display mode which means every field can be edited and saves automatically) and I would like to hide/remove the "Edit All" and "Show Comment" Icon as well as the directory of list item. The editing functionality for each item must remain.

Since I am not allowed to use Power Platform, is there any other option, e.g  JSON. Thanks in advance for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible using SharePoint JSON formatting capabilities to hide the "Edit All", "Copy link" or ["Show/Hide Comment"](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/09/all-you-need-to-know-about-commenting-in-lists/) options from display form of the SharePoint list.

Also, I don't think you can hide it using the Power Apps customized list forms capability.

I will suggest you to check for any existing feedback available on SharePoint feedback portal and vote on it so that Microsoft can allow this functionality in future.

If there is no existing feedback for this functionality, you can submit a new feedback/idea: [SharePoint feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online has no out-of-the-box way to hide hide/remove the "Edit All" and "Show Comment" Icon at this time.

But SharePoint Framework has the possibility to hide these buttons by means of code. SharePoint Framework can customize the pages of SharePoint Online.
You can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview